# How do you pack a 3-floats (space vector) into 4 bytes (pixel)?

Tags: graphics, packing

I've successfully packed floats with values in [0,1] without losing too much precision using:

```
byte packedVal = floatVal * 255.0f ; // [0,1] -> [0,255]
```

Then when I want to unpack the packedVal back into a float, I simply do

```
float unpacked = packedVal / 255.0f ; // [0,255] -> [0,1]
```

That works fine, as long as the floats are between 0 and 1.

Now here's the real deal.  I'm trying to turn a 3d space vector (with 3 `float` components) into 4 bytes.  The reason I'm doing this is because I am using a texture to store these vectors, with 1 pixel per vector.  It should be something *like* a "normal map", (but not exactly this, you'll see why after the jump)

[image: normal map]

So there, each pixel represents a 3d space vector.  Where the value is very red, the normal vector's direction is mostly +x (to the right).

So of course, normals are normalized.  So they don't require a magnitude (scaling) vector. But I'm trying to store a vector with *arbitrary* magnitude, 1 vector per pixel.

Because textures have **4** components (rgba), I am thinking of storing a scaling vector in the w component.

Any other suggestions for packing an arbitrary sized 3 space vector, (say with upper limit on magnitude of 200 or so on each of x,y,z), into a 4-byte pixel color value?

Answer (score 0):

Storing the magnitude in the 4th component sounds very reasonable. As long as the magnitude is bounded to something reasonable and not completely arbitrary.

If you want a more flexible range of magnitudes you can pre-multiply the normalized direction vector by (0.5, 1.0] when you store it, and when you unpack it multiply it by pow(2, w).

Answer (score 0):

Such method is used for storing high dynamic range images - RGBM encoding (M stands for magnitude). One of it's drawbacks is wrong results from interpolation so you can't use bilinear filtering for your texture.

You can look for other options from HDR encodings: [here is a small list of few most popular](http://lousodrome.net/blog/light/2013/05/26/gamma-correct-and-hdr-rendering-in-a-32-bits-buffer/)